# Two proofs on divergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis

For both proofs: suppose there exsists $N_0$ such that $s_n \leq t_n$ for all $n>N_0$

1. Prove that if $\lim s_n=+\infty$ then $\lim t_n=+\infty$

I have begun this proof with: Since $\lim s_n = \infty$ then for any number $M$ there exsists an $n$ such that $s_n>M$ for all $M,n \in \mathbb N$. By given, $t_n \geq s_n$ thus $t_n > M$. I am unsure of how to state that since $t_n$ is bigger than $M$ and $s_n$ that we can say $\lim t_n=+\infty$.

2. Prove that if $\lim t_n=-\infty$ then $\lim s_n=-\infty$

Similarly, I have started: Since $\lim t_n=-\infty$ then for all $M$ there exsists an $n$ such that $t_n<M$ for all $n,M \in \mathbb N$. But now if I use the given $s_n$ is smaller than $t_n$?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For your first proof, you're finished.  You've shown that $t_n > M$ for any number $M$ which is the definition of $t_n$ diverging to infinity.  For the second, you're doing the same thing as the first, but with the signs (both +/- and $\leq / \geq$ flipped.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $M>0$
>
> $s_n \to +\infty$ thus from the definition $\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_n>M,\forall n \geq N_1$
>
> From hypothesis exists $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $t_n>s_n,\forall n \geq N_2$
>
> Now take $N_0=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$
>
> So $\forall n \geq N_0$ we have that  $t_n >M$ proving that $t_n \to + \infty$ from the definition.

Using the same argument for the second statement,we have:

> Let $M>0$
>
> From the definition  $t_n \to -\infty$ thus exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $t_n <-M,\forall n \geq N_1$
>
> From hypothesis exists $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_n<t_n,\forall n \geq N_2$
>
> Thus taking $N_0=\max\{N_2,N_2\}$ we have that $s_n<-M,\forall n \geq N_0$ proving that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}s_n=-\infty$ from the definition.